# Test RSA-OAEP decryption using the google/wycheproof test vectors

Tags: encryption, rsa, oaep

I am trying to test RSAOAEP decryption using [google/wycheproof](https://github.com/google/wycheproof/blob/master/testvectors/rsa_oaep_2048_sha256_mgf1sha256_test.json) test vectors.

Below is the snippet of testvectors

```html
"testGroups" : [
    {
      "privateKeyPem" : "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\n3l7M0UPPMSQfWSG1rTmD+1TvF747KFNn5QyZnGcke1Uv5L/OlF97\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
      "privateKeyPkcs8" : "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",
      "sha" : "SHA-256",
      "type" : "RsaesOaepDecrypt",
      "tests" : [
        {
          "tcId" : 1,
          "comment" : "",
          "msg" : "",
          "ct" : "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",
          "label" : "",
          "result" : "valid",
          "flags" : []
        }
```

PrivateKey is given in pem and pkcs8 format.

Below is my sample code that I am trying but it is throwing "Data must not be longer than 256 bytes" error.

```html
    public byte[] decrypt(JSONObject testVector, String privateKeyPkcs8) throws Exception {
        byte[] ciphertext = Base64.getDecoder().decode(testVector.getString("ct"));
        byte[] temp = HexFormat.of().parseHex(privateKeyPkcs8);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(temp));

        String cipherTransformation = "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding";
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

        return plaintext;
    }
```

It looks like privateKeyPkcs8 is given in hex format. So I converted it into byte array and extracted the private key from it.

Can you please help what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: ct is obviously also hex encoded, so it must be hex (and not Base64) decoded.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you for looking into this. I Tried with "byte[] ciphertext = HexFormat.of().parseHex(ct)" as well. But it was giving "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException".

Comment: JCA/JCE defaults regarding the MGF1 digest to SHA1, you have to specify it explicitly for SHA256 with OAEPParameterSpec (in addition to the encoding fix), check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code:

- The ciphertext is hex encoded and therefore must be hex (and not Base64) decoded.
- The SunJCE provider defaults to SHA-1 for the MGF1 digest (the *SHA-256* in *RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding* refers to the OAEP digest), so SHA-256 must be *explicitly* specified for the MGF1 digest via [`OAEPParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/spec/OAEPParameterSpec.html).

  For the role of OAEP and MGF1 digest s. [RFC8017, sec. 7.1.  RSAES-OAEP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-7.1)

Fix:

```java
String privateKeyPkcs8 = "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";
String testvector = "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";

byte[] ciphertext = HexFormat.of().parseHex(testvector); // Fix 1: hex decoding
byte[] key = HexFormat.of().parseHex(privateKeyPkcs8);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key));

OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT); // Fix 2: specify SHA256 as MGF1 digest
String cipherTransformation = "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey, oaepParameterSpec);
byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

System.out.println(new String(plaintext, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

The plaintext is an empty `byte[]` (as specified in the test vector).

---

For completeness, unlike the SunJCE provider, the also commonly used BouncyCastle provider defaults to SHA-256 for the MGF1 digest when *RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding* is applied.

Comment: Thank you :)
I was not aware that MGF1 digest defaults to SHA1. It solved my issue.